# Uninstall feature (installed from Marketplace)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I installed *EGit* from Marketplace.

It crashed and stop to work (no 'Team' integration anymore, no branches displayed). I was planning to reinstall.

I go to *Help* -> *Installation Details*, search for *Git* and select all listed to uninstall. This *seems* to work, the features are not listed anymore in *Installation Details* (*Installed Software*).

But according to the Marketplace, the *EGit* stuff is still installed (therefore I cannot re-install)

[image]

When I press on the *Installed* button, after a few seconds an error message pops up:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error every time when I tried to see the installed Plugins in the marketplace.
For me the following solution worked:

Deleting the cache directory:

`\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache`

Refreshing the repositories via:

> Preferences` -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select
>   the entry and click the "Reload"

Some repositories could not be reloaded. They all belonged to one Plugin and I removed at first the broken repositories and then I deleted the Plugin (in my case I could delete it, it isn't in the list of installed Plugins but I haven't tried this before removing the broken repositories).

After that all worked fine again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I ended up starting all over with a fresh Eclipse installation.